# GTM Universal analytics events don't show up in Google Analytics.

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The Universal Analytics event tag that I have created is fired. It shows up in the Analytics Debugger as well as Network setting in developer options. But these events do not show up in my Google Analytics. Not in real time or in the old data.

Here you can see the value pushed to the data layer

Message pushed to Data Layer:

```
{

  gtm.element: http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/values/deleted/~3/L1nOc1Wi0Gc/,

  gtm.elementClasses: 'btn btn-default',

  gtm.elementId: '',

  gtm.elementTarget: '',

  event: 'gtm.click',

  gtm.elementUrl: 'http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/****/***/~3/L1nOc1Wi0Gc/'

}
```

But these events don't show up in GA. Not in real time nor when the data is processed by GA.

Comment: DId you make sure you didn't have a filter set up to block your own hits? Also, check that you are checking the correct property.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the events were not showing in GA was because the tracking ID I mentioned in the tag was wrong.. duhh.

I had used a variable to store the tracking ID but using variable for some reason was not working.. so i just manually entered it and then it worked!